# Diffing a single file across multiple branches in Git

Tags: git

Given a single file in a Git repo, how can I most easily `diff` across multiple local branches?  I could check out each branch one at a time and diff it against a common baseline, but I'm looking for a way to easily visualize the differences among 5 or more branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Given a single file in a Git repo, how can I most easily `diff` across multiple local branches?

Git's `git diff` really only compares two things at a time.  The two things can be entire commits / trees, or single files.

To name a commit, you can use any of the expressions described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), including branch names.  If you name a commit, `git diff` compares that commit's saved snapshot (its tree).  If you name a file, `git diff` compares that file.  As [the `git diff` documentation notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), when you want to compare, specifically, two files, you must name both files.  (This contrasts with, e.g., `git diff HEAD`, which compares the `HEAD` commit—or rather, its tree snapshot—to the entire working tree.)

> I could check out each branch one at a time and diff it against a common baseline ...

There is no need to check out a file to feed it to `git diff`:

```
git diff <revision>:<path> <revision>:<path>
```

names two of what Git calls *blobs*, which is its generic term for file, more or less.<sup>1</sup>  Hence if you wanted to compare the contents of the file `README.txt` in commit `a123456` to that of `README.txt` in commit `fedcba9`:

```
git diff a123456:README.txt fedcba9:README.txt
```

If the commit you want (e.g., `a123456`) is the tip commit of branch `develop`, the branch name works here:

```
git diff develop:README.txt fedcba9:README.txt
```

But, again, the comparisons are strictly pairwise: left-side file vs right-side file.

As [eftshift0 notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469176/diffing-a-single-file-across-multiple-branches-in-git/52469332?noredirect=1#comment91880831_52469332), if the file has the same *`path`* in both commits, you can have Git diff the commits and tell you about the one file:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- <path>
```

This is particularly useful if you want to diff several files, or an entire sub-tree:

```
git diff $old $new -- dir/sub/
```

gives you instructions for what to do with *every* file in `dir/sub/` in order to transform the contents of commit `$old` into the contents of commit `$new`, while:

```
git diff $old $new -- $file1 $file2
```

tells you about changes to both files, if both files are changed.

---

<sup>1</sup>"More", really, since Git stores symbolic link targets as blob content, for instance.

Comment: If paths are the same between revisions (they are most of the time), this can be done: `git diff revision1..revision2 -- some-path`. Using one of @toreks examples: `git diff a123456..fedcba9 -- README.txt`

Comment: @eftshift0: yes; you also don't need the two dots. In one sense this is making Git work harder (extract both commits, diff them all, then show only the one file's diff) but Git does optimize the task internally (extract both commits, throw out all but one file, diff the one file).

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful response, @torek!